# Joining unrelated table and finding available date

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, oracle11g

I have these two queries.

Query 1:

```
SELECT fex.availableID, fex.lecturerID, fex.freedate,
ex.lecturerID AS Examiner, ex.lecturerFullname,
v.availableID, v.availableDay, v.availableStart, v.availableEnd, v.availableEnd
FROM free fex
INNER JOIN lecturer ex
ON fex.lecturerID = ex.lecturerID
INNER JOIN availability v
ON fex.availableID = v.availableID
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT s.studentID, s.studentName, s.projectTitle, s.lecturerID AS supervisor,
sv.lecturerID, sv.lecturerFullname,
fsv.availableid, fsv.lecturerid, fsv.freedate
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN lecturer sv
ON s.lecturerID = sv.lecturerID
INNER JOIN free fsv
ON s.lecturerID = fsv.lecturerID
```

As you can see lecturer here plays two roles which are `supervisor` and `examiner`. Query 1 shows the query for `examiner`. Query 2 shows the query for `supervisor` and their students.

Database scheme:

Free:

```
availableID (number)
lecturerID (varchar2)
freedate (Date)
```

Lecturer:

```
lecturerID (varchar2)
lecturerFullname (varchar2)
```

Availability:

```
availableID (number)
availableDay (varchar2)
availableStart (Date) //Time
availableEnd (Date)   //Time
availableDate (Date)
```

Student:

```
studentID (varchar2)
studentName (varchar2)
Projecttitle (varchar2)
lecturerID(varchar2)
```

First of all, I would like to join these two queries. Since they are not related. I have tried using `CROSS JOIN` but I got infinity result.

Secondly, after the query is joined. I would like the query to find the `supervisor` OR the `examiner` in which one of them has value in `freedate` (eg: 10-05-2016). Since most of them will have NULL value in `freedate`. Only certain lecturers have value on it.

Then, it will produce a query result where it shows something like this:

```
studentID   studentName   projectTitle   supervisor   examiner   availableID  availableDay     freeDate
  123          hunter         abc           mary        kent        10           Tuesday         10-05-2016
```

For example, the examiner has `freedate` 10-05-2016. Meanwhile, supervisor has null value of `freedate`.

Or maybe there is any efficient way?

Comment: It's unclear how the data "joins" together. If you can include some sample data that matches up to your desired results, we may be able to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
SELECT fex.availableID, fex.lecturerID, fex.freedate,
ex.lecturerID AS Examiner, ex.lecturerFullname,
v.availableID, v.availableDay, v.availableStart, v.availableEnd, v.availableEnd
FROM free fex
INNER JOIN lecturer ex
ON fex.lecturerID = ex.lecturerID
INNER JOIN availability v
ON fex.availableID = v.availableID
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT s.studentID, s.studentName, s.projectTitle, s.lecturerID AS supervisor,
sv.lecturerID, sv.lecturerFullname,
fsv.availableid, fsv.lecturerid, fsv.freedate
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN lecturer sv
ON s.lecturerID = sv.lecturerID
INNER JOIN free fsv
ON s.lecturerID = fsv.lecturerID
WHERE sv.lecturerID = ex.lecturerID
) DQ
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the database tables, all have a common key to be joined.

> Database scheme:
>
> Free:
>
> availableID (number) lecturerID (varchar2) freedate (Date)
>
> Lecturer:
>
> lecturerID (varchar2) lecturerFullname (varchar2)
>
> Availability:
>
> availableID (number) availableDay (varchar2) availableStart (Date)
>   availableEnd (Date)   //Time availableDate (Date)
>
> Student:
>
> studentID (varchar2) studentName (varchar2) Projecttitle (varchar2)
>   lecturerID(varchar2)

```
    SELECT *
    FROM FREE FR, LECTURER LR, AVAILABILITY AV, STUDENT ST
   WHERE FR.AVAILABLEID = AV.AVAILABLEID
     AND LR.LECTURERID = FR.LECTURERID
     AND ST.LECTURERID = FR.LECTUREID
```

But, since you have mentioned that the two are different, You can use UNION for the same.

```
SELECT fex.availableID, fex.lecturerID, fex.freedate,
ex.lecturerID AS Examiner, ex.lecturerFullname,
v.availableID, v.availableDay, v.availableStart, v.availableEnd, v.availableEnd
FROM free fex
INNER JOIN lecturer ex
ON fex.lecturerID = ex.lecturerID
INNER JOIN availability v
ON fex.availableID = v.availableID
UNION
SELECT s.studentID, s.studentName, s.projectTitle, s.lecturerID AS              supervisor,
sv.lecturerID, sv.lecturerFullname,
fsv.availableid, fsv.lecturerid, fsv.freedate
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN lecturer sv
ON s.lecturerID = sv.lecturerID
INNER JOIN free fsv
ON s.lecturerID = fsv.lecturerID
```

The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the ALL keyword with UNION.